# Specify multiple source fields for a tertiary mapper

Tags: java, mapstruct

## Sample Objects

```java
public class Source {
    String fromPersonFirstName;
    String fromPersonLastName;
    String toPersonFirstName;
    String toPersonLastName;
    String message;
}

public class Target {
    Person from;
    Person to;
    String message;

}

public class Person {
    String firstName;
    String lastName;
}

@Mapper(componentModel = "spring")
public interface PersonMapper {
    Person toPerson(String firstName, String lastName);
}
```

## The Question

Now, what would be a clean way of employing as much as mapstruct as possible? Without using expressions?

Ideally I'd tell mapstruct to do the following

```java
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring", uses = PersonMapper.class)
public interface ExampleMapper {

    @Mapping(target = "from", source = "fromPersonFirstName, fromPersonLastName")
    @Mapping(target = "to", source = "toPersonFirstName, toPersonLastName")
    Target toTarget(Source s);
}
```

Alternatively I could annotate `PersonMapper` and `toPerson`, then for the `toTarget` method `qualifiedByName = "TheClassNameValue, TheMethodNameValue"`. But I still don't know how to tell the method which source fields to use.

What would be another option? I could use a local method `toPerson`, `qualifiedByName`. But then I'd have to import the other mapper in some way. Maybe change the `ExampleMapper` to abstract and autowire the other mapper. But I still can't specify multiple fields.

I know that `expression` is probably meant to fill in this gap. But ... I would rather never use it if possible. Unless the alternative is considerably more complicated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution 1, [Mapping method selection based on qualifiers](https://mapstruct.org/documentation/stable/reference/html/#selection-based-on-qualifiers)**

```java
@Mapper
public interface ExampleMapper {
    @Mapping(target = "from", source = "source", qualifiedByName = "fromPersonMapping")
    @Mapping(target = "to", source = "source", qualifiedByName = "toPersonMapping")
    Target toTarget(Source source);

    @Named("fromPersonMapping")
    @Mapping(target = "firstName", source = "fromPersonFirstName")
    @Mapping(target = "lastName", source = "fromPersonLastName")
    Person fromPersonMapping(Source source);

    @Named("toPersonMapping")
    @Mapping(target = "firstName", source = "toPersonFirstName")
    @Mapping(target = "lastName", source = "toPersonLastName")
    Person toPersonMapping(Source source);
}
```

Generated code:

```java
public class ExampleMapperImpl implements ExampleMapper {

    @Override
    public Target toTarget(Source source) {
        if ( source == null ) {
            return null;
        }
        Target target = new Target();
        target.from = fromPersonMapping( source );
        target.to = toPersonMapping( source );
        target.message = source.message;
        return target;
    }

    @Override
    public Person fromPersonMapping(Source source) {
        if ( source == null ) {
            return null;
        }
        Person person = new Person();
        person.firstName = source.fromPersonFirstName;
        person.lastName = source.fromPersonLastName;
        return person;
    }

    @Override
    public Person toPersonMapping(Source source) {
        if ( source == null ) {
            return null;
        }
        Person person = new Person();
        person.firstName = source.toPersonFirstName;
        person.lastName = source.toPersonLastName;
        return person;
    }
}
```

**Alternative with custom methods:**

```java
@Mapper
public interface ExampleMapper {
    @Mapping(target = "from", source = "source", qualifiedByName = "fromFieldsMapping")
    @Mapping(target = "to",  source = "source", qualifiedByName = "toFieldsMapping")
    Target toTarget(Source source);

    Person toPerson(String firstName, String  lastName);

    @Named("fromFieldsMapping")
    default Person fromFieldsMapping(Source source) {
        return toPerson(source.fromPersonFirstName, source.fromPersonLastName);
    }

    @Named("toFieldsMapping")
    default Person toFieldsMapping(Source source) {
        return toPerson(source.toPersonFirstName, source.toPersonLastName);
    }
}
```

Generated code:

```java
public class ExampleMapperImpl implements ExampleMapper {

    @Override
    public Target toTarget(Source source) {
        if ( source == null ) {
            return null;
        }

        Target target = new Target();

        target.from = fromFieldsMapping( source );
        target.to = toFieldsMapping( source );
        target.message = source.message;

        return target;
    }

    @Override
    public Person toPerson(String firstName, String lastName) {
        if ( firstName == null && lastName == null ) {
            return null;
        }

        Person person = new Person();

        if ( firstName != null ) {
            person.firstName = firstName;
        }
        if ( lastName != null ) {
            person.lastName = lastName;
        }

        return person;
    }
}
```

**With separate mapper:**

```java
@Mapper(uses = PersonMapper.class)
public interface ExampleMapper1 {
    @Mapping(target = "from", source = "source", qualifiedBy = FromAnnotation.class)
    @Mapping(target = "to", source = "source", qualifiedBy = ToAnnotation.class)
    Target toTarget(Source source);
}

@Mapper
public interface PersonMapper {
    Person toPerson(String firstName, String lastName);

    @FromAnnotation
    default Person fromFieldsMapping(Source source) {
        return toPerson(source.fromPersonFirstName, source.fromPersonLastName);
    }

    @ToAnnotation
    default Person toFieldsMapping(Source source) {
        return toPerson(source.toPersonFirstName, source.toPersonLastName);
    }
}

@Qualifier
@java.lang.annotation.Target(ElementType.METHOD)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.CLASS)
public @interface ToAnnotation {
}

@Qualifier
@java.lang.annotation.Target(ElementType.METHOD)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.CLASS)
public @interface FromAnnotation {
}
```

**Solution 2, [Expression](https://mapstruct.org/documentation/stable/reference/html/#expressions)**

```java
@Mapper
public interface ExampleMapper {
    @Mapping(target = "from", expression = "java(toPerson(source.fromPersonFirstName, source.fromPersonLastName))")
    @Mapping(target = "to", expression = "java(toPerson(source.toPersonFirstName, source.toPersonLastName))")
    Target toTarget(Source source);

    Person toPerson(String firstName, String  lastName);
}
```

Generated code:

```java
    @Override
    public Target toTarget(Source source) {
        if ( source == null ) {
            return null;
        }
        Target target = new Target();
        target.message = source.message;
        target.from = toPerson(source.fromPersonFirstName, source.fromPersonLastName);
        target.to = toPerson(source.toPersonFirstName, source.toPersonLastName);
        return target;
    }

    @Override
    public Person toPerson(String firstName, String lastName) {
        if ( firstName == null && lastName == null ) {
            return null;
        }
        Person person = new Person();
        if ( firstName != null ) {
            person.firstName = firstName;
        }
        if ( lastName != null ) {
            person.lastName = lastName;
        }
        return person;
    }
```

**Solution 3, regular mapping**

```java
@Mapper
public interface ExampleMapper {
    @Mapping(target = "from.firstName", source = "source.fromPersonFirstName")
    @Mapping(target = "from.lastName", source = "source.fromPersonLastName")
    @Mapping(target = "to.firstName",  source = "source.toPersonFirstName")
    @Mapping(target = "to.lastName",  source = "source.toPersonLastName")
    Target toTarget(Source source);
}
```

Generated code:

```java
public class ExampleMapperImpl implements ExampleMapper {

    @Override
    public Target toTarget(Source source) {
        if ( source == null ) {
            return null;
        }

        Target target = new Target();

        target.from = sourceToPerson( source );
        target.to = sourceToPerson1( source );
        target.message = source.message;

        return target;
    }

    protected Person sourceToPerson(Source source) {
        if ( source == null ) {
            return null;
        }

        Person person = new Person();

        person.firstName = source.fromPersonFirstName;
        person.lastName = source.fromPersonLastName;

        return person;
    }

    protected Person sourceToPerson1(Source source) {
        if ( source == null ) {
            return null;
        }

        Person person = new Person();

        person.firstName = source.toPersonFirstName;
        person.lastName = source.toPersonLastName;

        return person;
    }
}
```

Comment: I should have been way more clear. The target `to` and `from` are a generic type found everywhere. But there are literally hundreds of source objects. Each and every of these options would mean writing hundreds of convertors. I just need a way of specifying two fields, without having to write a new method for each and every source. I can, ofc, just autowire the mapper and use an expression. I just hardcore do-not-want-to. I would love to be able to just say: for this target, I have this named whatever, use these two source fields in the order specified. I however see no way of doing this.